# How to enable refreshing vault properties in an application using Spring Cloud Vault Kubernetes authentication

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

Kubernetes used to issue long-lived service account tokens. at some point this behavior was changed to issue 1hr tokens. when a token expires, the file contents of the service account token file (/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token) change.

Spring Vault used to cache the result of reading this file - and I've been able to find these references (the [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-vault/commit/28976b1fd5bd9ff25d7a651cc627ada202d5fbf0) and the [comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-vault/issues/449#issuecomment-514202800)) in the history suggesting that this behavior changed. What I can't do is figure out how to customize/enable it. For me, even if spring.cloud.vault.config.lifecycle.enabled is set to "true" - the services looses authentication with vault at the end of the hour and seems to be unable to re-read the file and re-auth with vault.

Maybe there is some sort of bean or something i have to define as well, but since the above linked github [issue comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-vault/issues/449#issuecomment-514202800) sounds like it is referring to the same exact think as this question, my question feels like sufficiently like a user error to indeed be a stackoverflow question rather than a github issue comment.